# Remove all text after the last instance of a string in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

So let's say I have a file that contains the following text:

```
string1
string1
string2
string1
string2
string1
string1
```

And I wanted to get rid of all text after the last occurrence of "string2". For example the output would look like this:

```
string1
string1
string2
string1
string2
```

What's an easy way to do this in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tac file | awk '!f && /string2/ { f=1 }; f' | tac
```

`tac` prints the file upside down. `awk` sets a flag on first occurence of the pattern `string2` (which is the last occurence in the original version) and prints a line only if the flag is set.

Comment: Thanks, you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

***grep*** approach:

```
grep -zo '.*string2' yourfile && echo
```

The output:

```
string1
string1
string2
string1
string2
```

---

`-z` - treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline

---

To write the result into a file do the following action:

```
(grep -zo '.*string2' yourfile && echo "")  > output.txt
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work for me? I only get two lines with `string2`.

Comment: @steffen, what's your OS and `grep` version?

Comment: `grep (GNU grep) 2.20`, OS is `CentOS release 6.9 (Final)`

Comment: Yes, I know, your answer makes perfectly sense to me (it will just load all the file content to RAM, but that's fine for most cases). I don't know why it doesn't work on my test machine. It like `-z` has no effect, but actually it does when run wihtout `-o` - then I get the whole file contents, not only the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a simple `grep` :

```
grep -B100000000 string2 yourfile
```

Just make that number bigger than the number of lines in your file.